# How to ignore a jQuery event when a certain button is clicked?

Tags: jquery

In my code I have an Ajax lookup bound to the `focusout` event of a textbox.  The Ajax request will display an error message if the data provided was invalid.  I also have a "cancel" button on a form that, when clicked, hides some fields including the one with the request.  However, if an invalid value is specified in the textbox, clicking the Cancel button fires off the Ajax request (because the textbox loses focus) and the error message gets displayed.

What I want is when I click the cancel button, this Ajax event is **not** fired, so even if the user entered an invalid entry the form will be "closed" without the error message displaying.

Is this possible?

Code is this, basically:

```
$('#txtPostalCode').focusout(function() { 
    postalCodeLookup($(this).val()); // ajax method wrapper
});

$('button#cancelButton').click(function() { 
    $('#txtPostalCode').attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled'); // applies CSS style to make textbox look like a label
    $('#txtPostalCode').val($('#oldPostalCode').val()); // restore old value
});
```

as I said since the focusout fires before the click, you can't "cancel" the form if there's an invalid entry in the textbox since it will fire the ajax request and come up with the error message.  This issue is from a usability point of view, in that someone might enter an invalid zip code, realize their mistake and then try to cancel the form, but the form won't let itself it be cancelled until they enter a valid zip code (which is then just overridden when the form actually does cancel).

If there's a better way to handle what I want to do I'm all for hearing that as well, this was the first thing that popped into mind when I received the requirement :)

Answer (score 1):

`focus` event will be fired before the cancel button's `click` event so you cannot do anything other than to abort the ajax request. Calling `abort` method on `XHR` object aborts the current request.

Alternatively you can have some delay before you trigger the ajax request on `focusout` event and within the time if you click on cancel button, clear the timeout.

Something like this.

```
$(function(){
    var xhr;
    $('input').focusout(function(){
        xhr = $.ajax({
                 ...
              });
    });

    $('.cancel').click(function(){
        xhr.abort();
        //other stuff
    });
});
```

Or

```
$(function(){
    var timeoutId;
    $('input').focusout(function(){
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){ 
            $.ajax({
                 ...
            });
        });
    });

    $('.cancel').click(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        //other stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: Option number 2 was helpful to me.  Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little hacky, but I would set a variable that switches on and off with hover on the cancel button. Then put an if block in your `focusout` code, allowing it to fire only when the afore mentioned variable is false.